# best way to clear a list in Python performance-wise

Tags: python

I am interested to know, if there is any performance difference between the two following ways of clearing a python list:
and if one of them is considered to be a better "best-practice"

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]

# method 1
my_list.clear()

# method 2
del my_list[:]
```

Comment: they are equivalent

Comment: These are both extremely bad practice because they involve a list variable named `list`.  The mechanism used to clear it is of very distant secondary importance.

Comment: I am relatively new to Python, so I might be wrong, but I think method 1 would be better. Since method 2 would delete the variable so when reusing it later in the code it needs to get created again whereas with .clear() it is still there just empty, just like running `list = []`

Comment: For one thing, don't name your list `list`, as it shadows the built-in list type. Regarding "any performance difference between the two" what are you defining as performance? Memory footprint, run time, processor usage? The `prun`, `timeit`, and `memit` modules can help profile your code to test for yourself

Comment: or I guess `list = []`, though technically it creates a new list.

Comment: a third method of clearing a list would be `list *= 0` a less known method but works just as well

Comment: @Rdimo nice. from my understanding that leverages the repeat syntax in python, i.e. `[1] * 2` becomes [1, 1]. So here `[1] * 0` becomes an empty list instead.

Comment: @Beembo No, the second method does the same as the first. The variable itself is not deleted.

Comment: See [Which is faster? — Fabulous adventures in coding](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @Beembo `list = []` (allocating a whole new list) isn't the same as `list.clear()` (no allocation).

Comment: I've rarely seen a need to clear a list at all, let alone worry about which of the two is faster.

Comment: @Samwise That's a minor point barely worth mentioning in context.

Comment: @Samwise The variable naming choice is obviously just for simplicity but any way i renamed it to avoid possible confusion...

Comment: @Rdimo I don't view this as a reader friendly implementation.
alghot i admit, i didn't know about this way

Comment: @chepner i don't find the fact that you rarely need to clear a list, relevant to the question

Comment: @J.Y. It underscores the point that the speed difference between the two is almost certainly not going to bottleneck your code's performance, in which case this entire question fails the [practical problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) test for being on-topic.